# Не могу проверить наличие класса

Tags: dom, обработка

```
let elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");       
document.addEventListener('click', func, false);

function func () {
    console.log (elem);

    if(elem.classList.contains('loggedInStateButtons')) {
    
                console.log ('chln');
        }
```

Говорит Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')
at HTMLDocument.func

Comment: Посмотрите что у вас в elem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в `elem` коллекция элементов, вы не можете проверить `classList` сразу у всех, вам нужно пройтись по каждому элементу из коллекции циклом.

```js
let elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");       
document.addEventListener('click', func, false);

function func () {
    //console.log(elem);
    for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      if (elem[i].classList.contains('loggedInStateButtons')) {
       console.log ('chln');
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="loggedInStateButtons"></div>
```

Comment: Реализовал, ошибок в консоли нет, но и код не выполняется

Comment: @МаксПетренко код привязан к клику в любом месте документа, можете попробовать без клика - `function func () {
    //console.log(elem);
    for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      if (elem[i].classList.contains('loggedInStateButtons')) {
       console.log ('chln');
      }
    }
} func();`

Comment: а что будет запускать функцию?

Comment: @МаксПетренко в конце часть, где она вызывается - `func()`

Answer (score 1):

Вроде проще сразу запросить элемент по нужному селектору 'div.loggedInStateButtons':

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="loggedInStateButtons"></div>

<script>
    elem = document.querySelectorAll("div.loggedInStateButtons");
    if(elem.length) {
        console.log ('chln');
        console.log (elem.length);
    }
</script>
```

А брать все дивы и искать в них - это в том случае, когда в документе по-любому они есть, но нужно проверить наличие таковых в определенной группе (детей какого-то элемента) или промониторить конкретный тег.

Comment: да, так эффективнее, опять же промониторить тег можно и вашим способом, точно также проверить детей в определенной группе - изменить селектор, только есть один момент - вы в условии присваиваете `elem`, а вывод в консоль должен быть при проверке - `if (elem.length)`

Comment: Да, я чуток провтыкал, в оно ж по любому выполнится. Но суть понятна. Исправил.

Comment: Можно, но по какой-то причине мне перебор для детей показался лучше.
Не помню почему. )) Бывает иногда такое... И да, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: если вспомните, то сообщите обязательно :)

Comment: только вот, если перебирать элементы, то можно производить действия над ними сразу при нахождении